# Where to store video to play in Android app like youtube or Udemy?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, video-streaming, android-video-player, cloud-storage

I am creating an Android App where users can buy video courses and watch them at any time inside the app(like Udemy). I am using Firebase realtime database for database but not finding any solution to store the video(also what type of player I should use). I am thinking there may be something in Google Cloud Platform for video storage but not getting the exact thing. Can anyone help me in this case? I have no previous experience with GCP. If you can answer please tell me in an easy way. No previous experience No code available

Comment: You should probably look into using a service like mux.com. There is a lot more to video hosting than just storage.

Comment: @user10089226 which video-palyer you using in your andoird app ? Please share your experience, as i need to use video player in my app and i am confuse which one to use ? Any help/suggestions will appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best place to store your BLOB is Cloud Storage (or firebase Storage, its equivalent in Firebase world).

Use a [multi-regional storage class](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes) and serve the content as a [static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website), But this static site will be in HTTP and soon, Chrome will block non HTTPS video/image.

For solving this, you can put a [loadbalancer in front of your bucket backend](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-bucket) and don't forget to click on CDN for allowing content caching and a better user experience.

You can find more inputs [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media-entertainment/architecture/live-streaming/) and in all the side menus around.

Comment: Is it possible to use google drive to store the videos and play using Android Media Player?

Comment: I don't know the performance of Google Drive and the compatibility with CDN. Why do you want to use a Google Drive (personal) storage space instead of entreprise-grade Cloud Storage?